# Flask app still trying to connect to localhost:27017 even though different mongo_uri is specified

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have created a flask app which connects to a mongod server for data. I am running both the mongod and flask in different docker containers. Below is my docker compose file and flask's docker file respectively .

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  flaskapp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerFile
    networks:
      - bridge_network
    depends_on:
      - mongodatabase
    ports:
      - 9000:5000
    container_name: compose_flaskapp

  mongodatabase:
    image: mongo
    networks:
      - bridge_network
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    container_name: compose_mongo
    command: mongod --bind_ip 0.0.0.0
    volumes:
      - mongodbdata:/data/db
     
networks:
  bridge_network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  mongodbdata:
```

```
FROM python

ENV PORT=5000

COPY . /flask
WORKDIR /flask

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE $PORT

WORKDIR /flask/src

ENTRYPOINT [ "flask","run","--host=0.0.0.0" ]
```

Since, the flask app and mongod will be running in different containers. I added the following mongo_uri in the flask config.

```
MONGO_URI = 'mongodatabase://mongodb:27017/UTA_Enrollment'
```

But when I run the flask app, it still tries to connect to localhost:27017 for connecting to database. Even though I mentioned a different address in config.
I get the below mention timeout error.

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 5f6446c74ed2387c4f5117c6, topology_type: Single, servers: 

[<ServerDescription('localhost', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('localhost:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused')>]>
```

Edited:
Below is my flask code:

```
from flask import Flask

from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine

from config import Config

from flask_restplus import Api



app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.from_object(Config)

#app.logger.info('%s -- moNGO uRI', app,config['MONGO_URI'])

print('%s -- moNGO uRI', app.config['MONGO_URI'])

#app.config["MONGO_URI"] = 'mongodb://mongodatabase:27017/UTA_Enrollment'

db = MongoEngine()

db.init_app(app)

api = Api()

api.init_app(app)

from application.routes import app

from application.apis import api
```

Another thing I noticed is that when I run the above code normally then the mongo uri is printed to the console, but when I run it in docker then it is not getting printed. The flask environment is set as development. Could this be the reason?

Also, I am using a dockerignore file to not copy pyc files. So issue does not seem to be related to cached precompiled files.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I think your `MONGO_URI` is set incorrectly.

Try this one instead:

```
MONGO_URI = 'mongodb://mongodatabase:27017/UTA_Enrollment'
```

Comment: What does your python code look like? It seems you're not using that "MONGO_URI" variable

Comment: I have added flask code with some comment please see in the question details.